# How Display Image on page After $on("fileSelected") in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How can I display an image after `$on("fileSelected")` in AngularJS?

I'm selecting a file using the following:

```
   $scope.$on("fileSelected", function (event, args) {
       debugger;
       $scope.$apply(function () {
           $scope.file = args.file;
       });
```

I need to display the image with the img `src` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
```

Comment: var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(index.file);